# avutil.so file error not loading ffpmeg library

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

below is my Gradle file I want to load avutil.so file fo FFMPEG
I added javabytedeco lib for ffmpeg and it to large in size so I added only JavaCV lib but it need .so file
when I run app it working good no error but when I try to create a video using ffmpeg I got error.

```
android {
  

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mghori.vimory"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk{
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a"
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ["libs"]
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
  
    
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.5.3'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacpp', version: '1.5.3'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacpp', version: '1.5.3', classifier: 'android-arm64'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacpp', version: '1.5.3', classifier: 'android-x86_64'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '4.2.2-1.5.3'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '4.2.2-1.5.3', classifier: 'android-arm64'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '4.2.2-1.5.3', classifier: 'android-x86_64'
}
```

and I got below error does any one solution please help me

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mghori.vimory, PID: 21519
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1176)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1109)
        at org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.avformat.Write_packet_Pointer_BytePointer_int.<clinit>(Write_packet_Pointer_BytePointer_int.java:21)
        at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<clinit>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:323)
        at com.mghori.vimory.UtilityClass.getRecorder(UtilityClass.java:113)
        at com.mghori.vimory.activity.saveoperation.setupVideoRecorder(saveoperation.java:153)
        at com.mghori.vimory.activity.VideoProcessingDialogActivity.onCreate(VideoProcessingDialogActivity.java:418)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7807)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil.AV_NOPTS_VALUE() (tried Java_org_bytedeco_ffmpeg_global_avutil_AV_1NOPTS_1VALUE and Java_org_bytedeco_ffmpeg_global_avutil_AV_1NOPTS_1VALUE__)
        at org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil.AV_NOPTS_VALUE(Native Method)
        at org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil.<clinit>(avutil.java:270)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1176)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1125)
        at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.tryLoad(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:103)
        at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<clinit>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:129)
```

Comment: Please try to use Gradle JavaCPP to manage the libs:
https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp#the-platform-plugin

Comment: Hello #samuel-audet, I have tried all sort of different options to run your latest libraries for Android. It is breaking for the missing class "NoClassDefFoundError: org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil".

With the below dependency it works,
javacv:1.4.1, ffmpeg:3.4.2-1.4.1

Comment: Hello @samuel-audet, I have tried all sort of different options to run your latest libraries for Android. It is breaking due to the missing class "org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil". I have also tried to put all the dependent Jar files in the project 'ffmpeg-4.3.1-1.5.4.jar', 'javacpp-1.5.4.jar' & 'javacv-1.5.4.jar'

With the dependency,
javacv:1.4.1, ffmpeg:3.4.2-1.4.1 it works.      But it does not work with javacv:1.5.4, ffmpeg:4.1-1.4.4

Comment: ffmpeg-4.3.1-1.5.4 works just fine for me. If you would like to get some help, you'll need to provide more details about error messages, etc that you get.